# how to fix navBar permanently on the page header?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have one problem for fixing a header and footer when the user trying to edit the textField so that onFocus keyboard affect to push the header. I am used position absolute and fixed but the problem is still there.please check the code blow

```
<html>
        <head>
           </head>
    <body>

    <div data-role="page" id="login"  style="background-image: url('img/bg.png');background-size: 100% 100%; margin-top: 0px; ">    
        <div data-role="header" id="Header" data-position="fixed">
                <img src="img/nav_bar.png"  width="100%" height="auto" />
        </div>
    <div data-role="footer" id="Footer" data-position="fixed" style="height:15%;">

                        <img src="img/Footer.png"  onclick="location.href='Register.html'" width="100%" height="auto"/>
                        <div class="ui-grid-a" style="width:100%">  
                        <div class="ui-block-a" > <img src="img/phone.png" width="100%" height="auto" id="phonedial" onclick="javascript:dialCall();" ></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b" ><img src="img/Website_link.png" width="100%" height="auto" id="website" onclick="javascript:websiteCall();"></div>
                        </div>
                </div>


            </div>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please specify your question. Which text field do you mean?

Comment: my kepad overlay on input textfield , how to solve this?